# Rearranging columns in a dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have the following data frame :

| Dependant var | independant var | p-value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Vd1 | Vi1 | 0.0345 |
| Vd1 | Vi2 | 0.0025 |
| Vd1 | Vi3 | 0.0005 |
| Vd1 | Vi4 | 0.0305 |
| Vd2 | Vi1 | 0.0800 |
| Vd2 | Vi2 | 0.0000 |
| Vd2 | Vi3 | 0.0005 |
| Vd2 | Vi4 | 0.0004 |

And I would like it to look like that instead :

| Dependant var | Vi1 | Vi2 | Vi3 | Vi4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Vd1 | 0.0345 | 0.0025 | 0.0005 | 0.0305 |
| Vd2 | 0.0800 | 0.0000 | 0.0005 | 0.0004 |

Is there an easy way to go about it ?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

Does this work:

```r
library("tidyr")
df %>% pivot_wider(Dependant_var, values_from = `p-value`,
                   names_from = independant_var)
```

```
# A tibble: 2 × 5
  Dependant_var    Vi1    Vi2    Vi3    Vi4
  <chr>          <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1 Vd1           0.0345 0.0025 0.0005 0.0305
2 Vd2           0.08   0      0.0005 0.0004
```